# How do I add an external ID retrospectively?

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc

I have a SugarCRM and OpenERP instance, and need to sync states (which change a lot), customers, organisations and some products.

Some of the above records are created when OpenERP was installed, some have been imported from CSV, and some have been entered by hand through the admin pages. This has left and unholy mash of different and missing external IDs on the records (e.g. the states).

Is there a way to clean up these external IDs? I can't see a way to do it through the admin pages, so is there a way through the APIs? Can I load up state "Alabama" and tell OpenERP "the external ID for this record is now US-AL"?

Similarly, when creating new states through the API (we have a global list that is growing all the time), can the external ID be set at the time it is created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit external IDs, both with database and interface. Go to Settings -> Technical -> Sequences & Identifiers -> External Identifiers and there you have it. It's the ir.model.data model, so in related table in database you will find that.

About creating - never heard of, never tried to.

Comment: This is close enough, thanks. I won't be messing with the database directly - there is too much business logic tied up in the models that would be skipped over if I did that. I have also found that exporting records will automatically create external IDs for records that don't have them. There is no [useful] control over the formats of those IDs, but I have accepted that this kind of fine control is going to be difficult in OpenERP/ODoo. It means keeping the external IDs in the source system if regularly syncing contacts etc.